# How to set up Raspberry Pi 4 to connect to a VPN server IPSec)

Tags: vpn

I am running Raspberry PI OS Lite 64 bit (Kernel 6.1) on my Raspberry Pi 4 model b (4GB).

I have a FritzBox router running an IPSec VPN server in another house. I need now to have the Raspberry Pi 4 to connect via VPN to said VPN server and on top.

All instructions I seem to be able to find instructions / tutorials how to configure the CLIENT side of such a VPN - all explanations are always targeting setting up and configuring the Raspberry Pi as a VPN server...

Comment: You could broaden your search from specifically Raspberry Pi to be "VPN client on debian or linux". Raspberry Pi is a Debian Linux system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the following answer that worked for me:

`sudo apt install vpnc`

then edit the `/etc/vpnc/default.conf`:

```
IPSec gateway my.awesome.vpn.server.com
IPSec ID username
IPSec secret p4ssw0rd
IKE Authmode psk
Xauth username Xusername
Xauth password Xp4ssw0rd
```

`sudo vpnc`

then starts the connection and

`sudo vpnc-disconnect`

shuts it down again.

Answer comes from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/324255/debian-jessie-easiest-way-to-connect-to-vpn-ipsec