# How to configure vpnc (IPSec) as a mandatory connection?

Tags: vpn

I have a RaspberryPi 4 model b (4GB) running RaspberryPi OS lite 64 bit (Kernel 6.1), which I have configured to connect to connect to my VPN server using `vpnc`:

```
IPSec gateway my.awesome.vpn.server.com
IPSec ID username
IPSec secret p4ssw0rd
IKE Authmode psk
Xauth username Xusername
Xauth password Xp4ssw0rd
```

For the setup, the RaspberryPi is using a wired connection to a router/gateway via which he establishes the VPN connection to the remote VPN server.

Unfortunately, I cannot configure said router. Furthermore, the VPN server doesnt have a fixed IP address and is relying on a DynDNS-like domain.

I need now to make sure that the RaspberryPi is not, i.e. never, allowed to connect to the Internet directly. All communication MUST flow via the VPN connection.

That means: In case the VPN server crashes, the connection is somewhat faulty, a config error occurs, the VPN connection drops for whatever reason - the RaspberryPi ***MUST NOT*** fall back to normally connecting to the Internet using the router as a gateway.

How can I configure this in a reliable way?

Comment: Why are you asking kind of the same question again, without even answer the comment on the previous one? https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/144593/how-to-set-up-raspberry-pi-4-to-always-connect-to-a-vpn-server-ipsec